# Excel - Freezing Top row shows duplicate top row

Tags: excel, excel-2016

This is no programming question, at least I wouldn't put it that way unless I needed VBA for that.

The issue I have is the following:

- When I freeze the top row 1:1 with Excel Ribbon Freeze Row command, it does freeze the top row when I scroll down and it works as expected. However, when I scroll back top again, I see the row 1:1 froze, and below it I see again row 1:1 , thus seeing the same row twice.
- It should be like this: having the row 1:1 froze, and when scrolled all the way to top, show the frozen 1:1 and the next row would be 2:2 and not 1:1 and it is now.

I'm using Excel 2016 on Mac; I'm not sure if this is a problem of this version or it always happens, I've searched a lot about this and found no one with the similar issue. It's not a big problem, it is just annoying to the the same row twice

Visualization of the issue:

[image]

My interest lies in solving the problem and I just noticed that maybe this question is more suited for the superuser forum of stack exchange, so I'm going to ask there the exact same question; in the meanwhile if someone has any tip please let me know, even if it requires VBA to solve this strange problem.

Comment: Tried unfreezing then refreezing?

Comment: @findwindow of course I did; didn't work, otherwise I wouldn't post this question here; do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did you split the window by accident?

Comment: I'm using Excel version 19 on mac; I pressed the button to freeze the top row but I guess that maybe it is splitting

Comment: Oh I also tried with VBA; but the same thing happens again and again

Answer (score 3):

https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304933-excel-for-mac/suggestions/12428436-freeze-panes-broken-in-15-19-1

> This is fixed in the next version (15.20) that will make it to you all in March. In the meantime, you can "snap" the frozen content back into the freeze pane by clicking in any of the duplicated rows or columns.

Comment: thank you for the link and the explanation! I guess my issue is solved ;)